# Pass an object to aspx page through WCF service

Tags: wcf

I'm trying to populate dropdown in the aspx page using the datasource returned by a WCF service.

1. call from aspx through javascript:

   ```
   function Initialize() {
       NameSpace.WCFClass.UserInfo(OnSuccess, OnFailure)
   }

   function OnSuccess(result) {
       var varResult = result;
   }

   function OnFailure(result) {
       var varResult = result;
   }
   ```
2. WCF Code(svc.cs file)

   ```
   public Array UserInfo()
   {
       List<MyClass> lstUser = List<MyClass>();
       // after reading the values
       return lstUser.ToArray();
   }
   ```

   It returns an array with values--works fine
3. Next thing is, it throws exception: OnFailure in the javascript: "The server method 'UserInfo' failed."

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/) or the [IE Web Developer Helper](http://projects.nikhilk.net/WebDevHelper/) to determine what results are being recieved from the server.

Can you update the question with the results after you've determined what's being returned to the web browser?